# Implication used in boolean condition

Tags: propositional-calculus

Sorry if this is a basic problem. Is the following true:

$(p \rightarrow q) \land p \land r \vDash q \land r$?

A little more detail, I am trying to determine the following:

if $p \rightarrow q$ then is the follwing true: $p \land r \rightarrow q \land r$?

Comment: Isn't it so that you can use truth-tables in order to prove that $(p\to q)\wedge r\models q\wedge r$ and then use completeness (I am not really familiar with logic)?

Comment: I am not sure, my knowledge of logic is relatively rudimentary.

Comment: with the $p\land$ it is true.  Without it you can have $p=q=\bot$.

Comment: See [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models) for the difference between $\vdash$ (i.e. the conclusion is *derivable* in the proof system from the premise) and $\vDash$ (i.e. the conclusion is *true* in every interpretation satisfying the premise).

Comment: Having said that, if we read $\vDash$ in place of $\vdash$, the answer is  : YES to both.

Comment: We can easily check them using the truth tables for $\to$ and $\land$.